# python dictionary one element as key and one list as value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

Hey I have 3 list one which I am using as key and rest are values

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']
list1 = ['network', 'pingworker', 'vpc', 'solution', 'ops', '1', '2', '3']
list2 = ['vlan', 'nms', 'jds', 'zabbix', '4', '5', '6', 'pqr', '8', '2', '2', '3sd']

abc = {}
abc = dict(zip(keys[0], list1))
print(abc)
```

output I am getting is:

```
{'k': 'network', 'y': 'vpc', 'e': 'pingworker', '1': 'solution'}
```

what I required is:

```
{'key1': 'network', 'pingworker', 'vpc', 'solution', 'ops', '1', '2', '3'}
```

and similarly:

```
{'key2': 'vlan', 'nms', 'jds', 'zabbix', '4', '5', '6', 'pqr', '8', '2', '2', '3sd'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
abc = dict(zip(keys, [list1,list2]))
print(abc)
```

output:

```
{'key2': ['vlan', 'nms', 'jds', 'zabbix', '4', '5', '6', 'pqr', '8', '2', '2', '3sd'], 'key1': ['network', 'pingworker', 'vpc', 'solution', 'ops', '1', '2', '3']}
```

I suppose you want `{'key1':[],'key2':[]}`

Comment: many thanks this works for me I will mark as verified after 8 min policy. And thanks for answering instead of negative ratings like others much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could even simply do:

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']
list1 = ['network', 'pingworker', 'vpc', 'solution', 'ops', '1', '2', '3']
list2 = ['vlan', 'nms', 'jds', 'zabbix', '4', '5', '6', 'pqr', '8', '2', '2', '3sd']

abc = {}
abc[keys[0]] = list1
abc[keys[1]] = list2
print(abc)
```

Answer (score 0):

how can you have multiple values for a single key? 
`{'key1': 'network', 'pingworker', 'vpc', 'solution', 'ops', '1', '2', '3'}` is not a valid python dictionary. 
If you want something like this: `{'key1': ['network', 'pingworker', 'vpc', 'solution', 'ops', '1', '2', '3']}`

you can simply write:

```
abc = {keys[0]: list1, keys[1]: list2}
```

or

```
abc = {}
abc[keys[0]] = list1
abc[keys[1]] = list2
```

Answer (score -1):

You could Do something like this maybe. Use the
`dictionary.setdefault(something[i], []).append(value)`

Where `something[i]` is your key1 value and value is the list of values in your array.

Do a nested for loop for keys in list 1 and for value in `range(len(list1))`.
Then while you do not reach the end of the list, append all the values.